# EncodingUtil.urlDecode method hitting the heap size

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, governorlimits, files

While uploading a file, we send base64 and urlencoded blob(3 MB size) to Apex. In apex method, while using `EncodingUtil.urlDecode` method, we are hitting the heap size limit. Below is sample code:

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Id> saveTheChunkFile(List<Id> parentIds, String fileName, String base64Data, String contentType, List<Id> fileIds){

        System.debug('heap size at start: '+System.Limits.getHeapSize());

        base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');
        if ( fileIds == null || fileIds.isEmpty() ) {
            fileIds = saveFiles(parentIds, fileName, base64Data );
        } else {
            appendToFile(fileIds, base64Data);
        }

        return fileIds;
    }
```

Strangely this same works fine in different scratch org with even bigger file size, but in another scratch org it throws Heap Size limit error on line `base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');` It seems it is doubling the heap size during execution of this method.

***Update: As per our understanding, standard Salesforce methods, should not add to heap size, which is what seems to be happening here.***

Difference between two scratch orgs is that in one of the org, lwc component is included in VF page using lightning out, while in another org lwc component is simply exposed to a custom tab.

Any help suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you delegate the work to an async task where you will have 12MB?

Comment: In all honesty i found heap size limits make working with files in Apex borderline impossible.

What we do instead is add `ContentVersion` with custom fields which then allows our triggers to attach it where it belongs. This way in the UX we use the built-in file upload controls and with REST API we are using SF standard endpoints which have much higher limits (some 37.5 meg for base64)

Comment: I am more concerned about inconsistent behavior of EncodingUtil.urlDecode method. As per my understanding, Salesforce standard methods should not add to heap size. But this is what I am seeing is happening here.